# Django dynamically restricting a form to specified fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know how best to dynamically restrict which fields are part of a ModelForm instance. Specifically,

```
class ModelWithManyFields(models.Model):
    many fields ....

class FormOfSelectedModelFields(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelWithManyFields
        fields = [  a dynamic list for model fields determined by the view  ]
```

What is the best way to create an instance of `FormOfSelectdModelFields()` with a list of fields dynamically determined by some logic inherent from the view?

Comment: By "some logic inherent" from the view, do you mean you want the ModelForm to automatically figure out what fields to hide? If so, how would that be determined? Based on the request? Some other property?

Comment: Poor choice of words. The idea is a simple one. When the `View` seeks to fetch an instance of the `Form`, the `View` will provide a list of model fields so that the `Form` instance -- `form()` -- is only for that specific set of fields. Within the `View` is the logic to determine which form-fields are needed for the context it builds and passes to the template. My guess is my question is less clear now :)

Comment: The package [extra views](http://git.io/y8c1RQ) could help you out here. Use ModelFormSetMixin and override the `get_factory_kwargs` method to update the desired fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you probably want to create something like factory for this ModelForm.

In simple case you probably just want to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function